# ttest and pvalue estimates by row using R

Tags: r

I'm having trouble applying the `t.test` to the following set of data. For each locus, I would like to compare the 3 controls against the 3 test numbers.

**input**

```
 locus ctrl1 ctrl2 ctrl3 test1 test2 test3
  LOC1 43.10 34.15 39.26 34.64 32.78 34.94
  LOC2 80.54 76.72 74.58 76.00 78.03 72.15
  LOC3 30.25 51.90 40.12 68.54 74.44 69.51
```

I have applied the following script but I don't believe its performing the task correctly and, because the resulting p-values don't look correct, I suspect that it's calculating the global comparison instead of a row by row one.

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
data<-read.table(input,header=FALSE,sep=',', na.strings='NA',blank.lines.skip=TRUE)
frame=data.frame(data[1:7])
pvalue=apply(as.matrix(frame),1,function(x)
{t.test(as.numeric(x[2:4]),as.numeric(x[5:7]),na.rm=T)$p.value})
```

I would really appreciate any thoughts or inputs to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand why and how you are manipulating your data (why do you put "header=F" in your import when it seems that your input does include a header ? why do you transform your data into a matrix, which, due to the first column, is necessarily a character one ?) but the call to apply seems right to me, i.e, it does apply your function by row.
You should get pvalues of 0.21,0.48 and 0.03. Isn't that what your are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thanks for your comments.

I've made some minor changes and the following script now appears to work on this test dataset and on my larger one.

```
data<-read.table(input,header=TRUE,sep='\t', na.strings='NA',blank.lines.skip=TRUE)
frame=data.frame(data[2:7])
pvalue=apply(frame,1,function(x) {t.test(x[1:3],x[4:6], alternative = "two.sided", paired = TRUE)$p.value})
```